# Connection to specific firebird 2.5 server is slow

Tags: networking, firebird

I have the following setup:

- Two laptops connected to a network using the same switch
- Multiple Windows Server running Firebird 2.5.

My problem is that when I try to connect to one specific firebird server (172.16.2.106) using my first laptop (172.16.4.67) it's incredibly slow and takes minutes to load the tables (using IBExpert, queries run through a web script are also that slow).

Connecting to another firebird server in the same network (172.16.2.105) is fast and shows no problems.

When I try doing the same with my second laptop (172.16.4.66) the connection to the same server (172.16.2.106) is fast.

I tried

- Swap the ports, so the first laptop uses the port from the second and the second the port from the first laptop.
- Use a new LAN cable.

The laptops are the same model, run the same OS and software.

What could cause my first laptop having such a slow connection while the other laptop is fast?